# Canon 70D wifi cannot be enabled

Tags: canon, camera-settings, canon-70d, wifi

I bought two Canon EOS 70D and I can enable Wifi for one of them with no problem. But for the second camera, wifi seems deactive and I cannot click on Wifi options at all as can be seen in attached picture. Anyone has any idea what's the problem? Any additional setting needed?
Thanks

here is how Wifi menu looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind, the 70D has been produced in two different versions. A version with and one without WiFi. Ensure you are certain that one of the two cameras you have is not the WiFi-less type of the 70D. This can be seen on the label on the bottom of your camera, it should state if it is a 70D (W) or a 70D (N) where the 'N' version is the WiFi-less variant.

Otherwise it might be as Aganju suggested in his answer, that an already enabled setting prevents you from enabling WiFi at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

The Canon EOS series disables Wifi if you enable HDR, or certain other functions (there seems to be no logic behind it).